# ExtentReport is not generated in Maven repository

Tags: selenium, maven, report, extend

I have added the extent report dependency from the maven repository in pom.xml but when I am trying to use "ExtentSparkReporter" in my code, the import is not happening.
Below is my pom.xml

```
<groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
<artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
<version>4.0.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Below is my file:

```
public void config()

{
    
String path =System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\reports\\index.html";

ExtentSparkReporter reporter = new ExtentSparkReporter(path);
//no methods have been initiated in config


}
public void initialDemo()

{



System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://chromedriver.exe");

WebDriver driver =new ChromeDriver();

driver.get("https://www.google.com");

System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

driver.close();

//test.fail("Result do not match");



}
}
```

It will be a great help if anyone helps me regarding this.

P:s - As I have checked some of the solution to downgrade the extendreports library , so I am using 4.0.9.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you are missing some key components:

1. The ExtentSparkReporter needs to be attached to the ExtentReports object
2. You need to flush the ExtentReports object at the end of all tests

Here's a sample using 5.0.9  ( it works with 4.0.9 also)
Using these maven dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.4.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.9</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I'm using testng to manipulate the order the code is executed.

```
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentSparkReporter;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.*;

public class TestDemo {

    public ExtentReports extent = new ExtentReports();
    public ExtentSparkReporter reporter;
    public ExtentTest test;

    public WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeSuite
    public void beforeSuite() { // it will be executed only once, before all the tests, so we won't have duplicate reports or override the file for each test

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://chromedriver.exe");  //set the chrome path for all tests only once

        String path = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\reports\\index.html";

        reporter = new ExtentSparkReporter(path);

    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod(){

        driver = new ChromeDriver(); // create the chrome instance before each tests
    }


    @Test
    public void aFastTest() {

        test = extent.createTest("aFastTest");

        driver.get("https://www.google.com");

        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

        driver.close();

        test.fail("Failed");

    }

    @Test
    public void anotherTestPassed() {

        test = extent.createTest("anotherTestPassed");

        driver.get("https://www.google.com");

        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

        driver.close();

        test.pass("hey my test passed");

    }



    @AfterSuite
    public void afterSuite(){ //executed after all the tests have ran

        extent.attachReporter(reporter);
        extent.flush();
    }


}
```